# Viewing/creating/editing Google My Maps KML files on Android

Tags: kml, android, iphone, google-mymaps

I have two large (several hundred features) maps created by Google My Maps that I use for my field research. They contain important information required by the field crew for their work on site.

Currently these maps are accessed via iPhone by using a free app called My Maps Editor. This allows each individual to view all the features as well as create and edit new features as needed, that the rest of the crew will view.

However, I have been wanting to switch from iPhone to Android for a very long time. Currently the ONLY thing holding me back is that I can't get the same functionality on Android that I can on Iphone. Yes, Google's native maps and Google Earth apps allow you to VIEW the My Maps, but there are several limitations which make this essentially useless. What I need is to be able to:

- View multiple maps overlaid (Google only shows one at a time)
- View ALL features on each map (Google caps off at around 200 and arbitrarily decides which ones to show)
- View and edit these features (Google does not match the names with the features, and does not allow existing features to be edited).

Is anyone aware of an app that allows this on Android?

Alternatively, is anyone aware of another strategy that might allow KML files to be accessed via mobile phones over 3G?

Answer (score 2):

You have can have a look at [OSMNavigator](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/).

- View multiple maps overlaid (Google only shows one at a time) => Not sure what you mean.
- View ALL features on each map (Google caps off at around 200 and arbitrarily decides which ones to show) => Yes. It reasonably handles KML files of 2 Mb.
- View and edit these features (Google does not match the names with the features, and does not allow existing features to be edited). => Partially. This is not a full-features editor, but you can:

  - open a KML file from a URL (over the network, whatever it is)
  - open a local KML or KMZ file
  - add a Point/a route,
  - navigate in the hierarchy,
  - Cut/Copy/Paste,
  - hide/show,
  - edit some attributes: title, description, colors.
  - and you can save the final result on the device.